# gsutil compose fails composing file larger than 250mb

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-composer, gsutil

To move a medium sized blob (>250mb) from one place to another in GCS (`gsutil cp my_blob my_new_blob`),

gsutil wants me to compose it :

[image]

so I am doing `gsutil compose my_blob my_blob` to compose it and overcome this error, but I then get another error:

[image]

where it would just retry again and again and I would finally get a

> 503 - We encountered an internal error - Try again

error.

Why is this happenning ? Is there a limit to the size of the file to be composed and why this limit would be only 250mb ?

Comment: Is this just 1 file? If so, you shouldn't be using compose, compose is used when you have a multi-part file, that you uploaded in chunks using: gsutil cp -m, this is the documentation: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/compose, and the limit of filesize per copy is 5TB.

Comment: I can not use gsutil cp -m because the file has been uploaded via the S3 API and gsutil wants me to compose it first, even if it's a single object. See : https://github.com/peak/s5cmd/issues/217 , and https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/migrating#methods-comparison

Comment: I composed Gb files without any problem. The issue should come from the single file composition.

Comment: Oh that information was missing, also if you are bringing the file from s3 you can use: STS ( Storage Transfer Service ). This supports S3 sources and move them into a bucket: https://console.cloud.google.com/transfer/cloud/

Answer (score 1):

Trid it on my end using this docs [Cloud Storage cp options](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/cp#options).

> > $ gsutil -o "GSUtil:max_upload_compression_buffer_size=8G" -m cp -J filetest filtest_new
> > Copying file://filetest...
> > / [1/1 files][300.0 MiB/300.0 MiB] 100% Done
> > Operation completed over 1 objects/300.0 MiB.

Tried to simplify it, same Chaotic comments with slight changes

> gsutil -m cp filetest filtest_new

XXXXX@cloudshell:~ (XXXXX)$ gsutil -m cp filetest filtest_new2
Copying file://filetest...
/ [1/1 files][300.0 MiB/300.0 MiB] 100% Done
Operation completed over 1 objects/300.0 MiB.

Comment: I can not use gsutil cp because the file has been uploaded via the S3 API and gsutil wants me to compose it first, even if it's a single object. See : https://github.com/peak/s5cmd/issues/217 , and https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/migrating#methods-comparison

Comment: Can you share reproducable steps for us to check?